# ECS and appropriate usage in games

Tags: c++, entity

I've been reading about Entity-Component-Systems and i think i understand the basic concept:

Entities are just IDs with their Components stored in Arrays to reduce cache misses. Systems then iterate over one or more of these Arrays and process the data contained in the Components.

But i don't quite understand how these systems are supposed to efficently and cleanly interact with one and another.

1: If my entity has a health component, how would i go about damaging it?
Just doing `health -= damage` wouldn't account for dying if health goes below or equal 0. But adding a `damage()` function to the component would defy the point of components being only data. Basically: **How do systems process components which need to respond to their changes and change other components based on their changes?** (Without copy-and-pasting the damage code into each system which can possibly inflict damage)

2: Components are supposed to be data-only structs with no functions. How do i best approach entity-specific behaviour like exploding on death. It seems unpractical to fill the Health component with memory-wasting data like `explodesOnDeath=false` when only one or two out of many entities will actually explode on death. I am not sure how to solve this elegantly.

Is there a common approach to these problems?

Ease of modification (for ex with Lua scripts) and high chances of compatibility are important to me, as i really like games with high modding potential. :)

Used Language: C++

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am also new to the field, but here are my experiences with ECS models:

**How do systems process components which need to respond to their changes and change other components based on their changes?**

As you correctly pointed out, the components are just containers of data, so don't give them functions. All the logic is handled by the systems and each new piece of logic is handled by a different system. So its a good choice to seperate the logic of "dealing damage" from "killing an entity". The comminication
between the *DamageSystem* and the *DeathSystem* (with other words, when should an entity be killed) can the be based on the *HealthComponent*.

**Possible implementation:**

You typically have one system (The *DamageSystem*) that calculates the new health of an entity. For this purpose, it can use all sorts of information (components) about the entity (maybe your entities have some shield to protect them, etc.). If the health falls below 0, the *DamageSystem* does not care, as its only purpose is to contain the logic of dealing damage.

Besides the *DamageSystem*, you also want to have some sort of *DeathSystem*, that checks for each entity if the health is below 0. If this is the case, some action is taken. As every entity does sth on their death (which is the reason why your `explodesOnDeath=false` is not a bad idea), it is usefull to have a *DeathComponent* that stores some kind of enum for the death animation (e.g. exploding or just vanishing), a path to a sound file (e.g. a fancy exploding sound) and other stuff you need.

With this approach, all the damage calculation is located at one place and seperated from e.g. the logic of the death of an entity.

Hope this helps!

Comment: If i understand correctly, i would damage an entity like this `systems.dmgSystem.damage(entityID,...);` , right? And the Damagesystem notifies the Deathsystem in the same way?

Comment: @ShroomPow if the Damagesystem would notify the Deathsystem, the Damagesystem would contain the logic of when to kill entities. You can do that. But on most implementations I have seen, the systems are not called on demand, but a system is called on each frame for all entities. If the Damagesystem would be called on an entity without health component, it would ignore the entity and it would move on to the next. After the Damagesystem has finished processing an entity, the Deathsystem is called on each entity. If an entity does not fulfill the kill requirements ( health > 0) it is ignored

Comment: This is advantagous e.g. imagine in your game there is a possibility to have a second live, so `health <= 0` does not necessarily mean to kill an entity. You definitely dont want to let the Damagesystem handle the logic of second lives as well. But all I wrote is just a suggestion :)